# flask and mysql error (pymysql.err.InternalError) (1525, \"Incorrect DATETIME value: '1399-02-30 '\")\n

Tags: mysql, flask

this part off back-end code working in my local server fine !

but not work in remote(main) server !!!

my back-end error in main server:

```
{"status_code": 400, "description": "(pymysql.err.InternalError) (1525, \"Incorrect DATETIME value: '1399-02-30
'\")\n[SQL: SELECT count(*) AS count_1 \nFROM (SELECT discount.id AS discount_id, discount.user_id AS discount_user_id,
discount.s_time AS discount_s_time, discount.e_time AS discount_e_time, discount.code AS discount_code,
discount.percentage AS discount_percentage, discount.is_private AS discount_is_private \nFROM discount \nWHERE
discount.s_time < %(s_time_1)s AND discount.e_time>= %(e_time_1)s AND discount.code = %(code_1)s AND discount.user_id =
    %(user_id_1)s) AS anon_1]\n[parameters: {'s_time_1': '1399-02-30 ', 'e_time_1': '1399-02-30 ', 'code_1': 'v',
    'user_id_1': 81}]\n(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/2j85)"}
```

local server:

```
system_time_zone
Iran Daylight Time
time_zone
SYSTEM
```

main server

```
system_time_zone    430
time_zone   Asia/Tehran
```

local server info:

```
 Database server
 Server: MySQL (127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP)
 Server type: MySQL
 Server connection: SSL is not being used Documentation
 Server version: 5.7.28 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
 Protocol version: 10
 User: root@localhost
 Server charset: cp1252 West European (latin1)
 Web server
 Apache/2.4.41 (Win32) PHP/7.4.0
 Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 7.4.0
 PHP extension: mysqliDocumentation curlDocumentation mbstringDocumentation
 PHP version: 7.4.0
```

my main server info :

Database server

```
Server: ------ via TCP/IP
Server type: MySQL
Server connection: SSL is not being used Documentation
Server version: 8.0.20 - MySQL Community Server - GPL
Protocol version: 10
User: root@172.17.0.1
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8mb4)

Web server

Apache/2.4.38 (Debian)
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 7.4.4
PHP extension: mysqli Documentation curl Documentation mbstring Documentation
PHP version: 7.4.4
```

Comment: There is no 30th day in February.

Comment: As @Akina says, not even in 1399 existed the 30th day of February

Comment: 1399 is a jalaly datetime.